# Add Days to Date with 'YYYYMMDD' format

Tags: datetime, vb6

In VB6, I am trying to add days to a date which is in the format 'YYYYMMDD'. I can add days like this:

```
Pull_Date = Need_Date + Val(txtLeadTime.Text)
```

which works, until the resulting days is greater than the number of days in the month.  I tried using DateAdd, but it doesn't accept the YYYYMMDD format - neither does CDate.

Comment: Work with VB. Write a function to change the format to one VB recognizes at a date, use the DateAdd method, change the format back and return the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your date string to a date so you can use the [DateAdd function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262710(v=vs.60).aspx):

```
Dim Need_Date  As String
Dim Pull_Date As Date
Dim tmpDate As Date

Need_Date = "20141113"
tmpDate = CDate(Mid$(Need_Date, 5, 2) & "/" & Right$(Need_Date, 2) & "/" & Left$(Need_Date, 4))

Pull_Date = DateAdd("d", Val(txtLeadTime.Text), tmpDate)
MsgBox Format$(Pull_Date, "yyyymmdd") '// if LeadTime is 25 days, displays 20141208
```

Please note, parsing your `Need_Date` by character position can blow up if it's not formatted exactly as expected.

Comment: `CVDate()` is a slow and obsolete function only present to help old projects work without upgrading.  The function you want is `CDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper into this old code, I found that a conversion function was already created:

```
Public Function Date_Format_YYYYMMDD(ByVal sDate As String) As String
    If IsDate(sDate) Then
        sDate = Format(sDate, "YYYYMMDD")
    End If

    Date_Format_YYYYMMDD = sDate
End Function
```

With this function, it's really easy:

```
 Pull_Date = Date_Format_YYYYMMDD(Need_Date) + Val(txtLeadTime.Text)
```

The only thing I don't understand is why

```
Pull_Date = Format(Need_Date, "YYYYMMDD") + Val(txtLeadTime.Text)
```

doesn't work.  Seems like it's doing the same thing as the function.

Comment: I don't know how it's working. The IsDate function fails for me when I pass "20141113".

Comment: And the `Format()` call just converts a String to a Date impicitly, then back to a String explicitly... assuming it works for anyone in any locale anyway.  Strings are not Dates.

Comment: Strange, I tested it several times yesterday and it seemed to be working.  Today it isn't.  Guess I was doing something incorrect yesterday.  The solution below worked for me.